# How to select first X values of Pivot Filter, in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I've got a "Day" filter in a Pivot table with the past 6 months, in the following format: "2/23/2016". Those values will change every day as I add more days, but I need a VBA script to select the first 30 values starting from the bottom. I can hard code "Filter "2/23/2016", but I want to dynamically select "The first 30 from the bottom" no matter what they are. Screenshot for some clarity:
[image: Pivot Filter]

Comment: Do you need someone to write the VBA code for you? Or have you already done something which is not working?

Comment: I do not have any VBA code for this purpose yet. I do however have
    
`With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Day")`
`.PivotItems("1/25/2016").Visible = False`

This is the basic VBA code for specific pivot item inclusion/exclusion. However, it doesn't help much in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Day").CurrentPage = "(All)"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Day")

    c = 5

    For i = .PivotItems.Count To 1 Step -1
       If (c > 0) Then
       .PivotItems(i).Visible = True
       Else
       .PivotItems(i).Visible = False
       End If
       c = c - 1
    Next
End With
```

I solved it. Here it is. C is how many values from the bottom you want to make visible.